# Highcharts tickPositions problems

Tags: highcharts

I have a weekly chart to display data of 3 years in weeks, 
And the chart have 2 XAxis, one show the week number , the other one show the year,
[Screen Capture of the chart](http://postimg.org/image/amcgcakoz/)
Both Axis have the same data Length, but different tick Length,
the Year XAxis label only show on the tick where week number equal to 1
(I have set offset to the Year Axis, so it not exactly shown below the week number 1)

Now I want to display Year Axis Tick when week number equal to 1 only.
So I add **"tickPositions"** with array [0,53,105] 
(position of week number of those 3 year) to Year Axis,
but the chart become:
[Screen Capture after adding "tickPositions"](http://postimg.org/image/va989ugj9/)
Since I only add 3 tick according to the array, why there are so many ticks on the chart?
And how can I fix it? Thank you very much! :)

Thanks Sebastian, after I include the plug-in to the page, it show below error:
Have you seen it before? Thanks!
Another question, I also have a same chart that show daily data, how can I group date time chart? Thanks!
Screen Capture of the error__http://postimg.org/image/iqgfspxqt/


My Year xAxis code:

```
{
        labels: {
            align: 'left',
            x: 25,
            formatter: function () {
                var ex = this.axis.getExtremes();
                if ((ex.max - ex.min) > 30) {
                    if (xCategoriesWeekNum[this.value] == 1)
                        return xCategoriesYear[this.value];
                }
                else if (((ex.max - ex.min) > 10)) {
                    if ((xCategoriesWeekNum[this.value] == 1) || ((xCategoriesWeekNum[this.value] % 10) == 0))
                        return xCategoriesYear[this.value];
                }
                else {
                    if ((xCategoriesWeekNum[this.value] == 1) || ((xCategoriesWeekNum[this.value] % 5) == 0))
                        return xCategoriesYear[this.value];
                }
            }
        },
        //offset: 0,
        lineWidth: 0,
        tickLength: 12,
        tickPosition: 'inside',
        tickInterval: 1,
        tickPositions: [0, 53, 105],
        tickPlacement: 'on',
        //tickPositioner: function () {
        //    var ex = this.chart.xAxis[0].getExtremes();
        //    alert(getTickPosition(ex.min, ex.max));
        //    return getTickPosition(ex.min, ex.max);
        //},
        title: {
            text: 'Week Number',
        },
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: false,
        minPadding: 0,
        maxPadding: 0,
    }],
```

My Week xAxis code:

```
[{
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                var ex = this.axis.getExtremes();
                if ((ex.max - ex.min) > 30) {
                    if ((xCategoriesWeekNum[this.value] == 1) || (xCategoriesWeekNum[this.value] == 7) || (xCategoriesWeekNum[this.value] == 13) || (xCategoriesWeekNum[this.value] == 19) || (xCategoriesWeekNum[this.value] == 25) || (xCategoriesWeekNum[this.value] == 31) || (xCategoriesWeekNum[this.value] == 37) || (xCategoriesWeekNum[this.value] == 43) || (xCategoriesWeekNum[this.value] == 49)) {
                        return xCategoriesWeekNum[this.value];
                        //if (xCategoriesWeekNum[this.value] == 1)
                        //    return xCategoriesWeekNum[this.value] + '<br>' + xCategoriesYear[this.value];
                        //else
                    }
                }
                else {
                    return xCategoriesWeekNum[this.value];
                }
            }
        },
        tickPixelInterval: $('#' + container).width() / dataLength,
        tickInterval: 1,

        showLastLabel: true, 
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: false,
        minPadding: 0,
        maxPadding: 0,
    }
```

Comment: Does your data use category type of xAxis?If yes you can use a [grouped_categories plugin](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/11/Grouped-Categories).

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, I tried the plugin, but it show an error, please kindly find the link of screen capture in m update, thanks!

Comment: I have found the version of my high charts cannot support the plugin, I will check it later, thank you very much, and one more question, can I group datetime in some other ways? thanks!

Comment: Nope, only category type.